Caused by:NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type available: expected single matching bean but found 2
problem statement: conflict between two beans with same name
example scenario
Inteface
public interface FakeInterface{
}

implementations which will act as beans
@Slf4j
@Service
public class IfakeInterfaceOne1 implements FakeInterface{
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public class IfakeInterfaceTwo2 implements FakeInterface{
}

main problem comes from here where im auto wiring it
somewhere in the project
@Autowire
FakeInterface myInterface;

NOTE
I dont want to touch the IfakeInterfaceOne1 class because it is using by many other classes
any experiments can we do is with IfakeInterfaceTwo2
pls help me in this.
thanks, in advance.

If you autowire the interface it won't be able to decide which of the 2 implementations it should use, so an exception is returned.
You could use qualifier to disambigaute between the two implementations. For example:
@Slf4j
@Service
@Qualifier("one")
public class IfakeInterfaceOne1 implements FakeInterface{
}

@Slf4j
@Service
@Qualifier("two")
public class IfakeInterfaceTwo2 implements FakeInterface{
}

and then when you autowire it:
@Autowired
@Qualifier("one") 
FakeInterface myInterface;

in this example the first implementation of FakeInterface will be used

thanks for the quick reply
i'm not allowed to modify IfakeInterfaceOne1 class. and many other classes are using it with simple autowire without qualifier. so i created a class IfakeInterfaceTwo2 for my use case, any experiments can do in this

Maybe you can autowire your implementation itself instead of the interface?
